# Can't get data from Form to Email

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a simple form and I've tried everything, from changing POST to GET to REQUEST. single quote, double quote. EOD... nothing worked. I get the confirmation page, I get subject and text back in the email, but no data. Please help!!

**signup.html**

```
<form action="/signupprocess.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="signup"
 target="_blank" id="signup">
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="35" maxlength="90">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="35" maxlength="80">
<input name="address" type="text" id="address" size="35" maxlength="90">
```

**signupprocess.php**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$account = $_POST['account'];
$authorize = $_POST['authorize'];

$body = <<<EOD
Name: $name <br>
Address: $address <br>
Phone Number: $phone <br>
Account: $account <br>
Authorize: $authorize <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $to\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
```

Comment: By `getting text back` and `no data`, what do you mean and can you be more specific?

Comment: Can you show the lines where you define `$to` and `$subject`?

Comment: so you get the email but the body($body) is blank ?

Comment: There is nothing in your form for `$phone, $account and $authorize`, unless you're not showing us the entire codes for your form?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `enctype` attribute in the `<form>`

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but that got rid of the text altogether, which is Email:  
Name:  
Address:  
Phone Number:  
Account:  
Authorize:

Comment: $subject = 'Contest Signup';
$to = 'mysite@aol.com';

Comment: @Fred
Sorry. I didn't show $phone, $account, $authorize but it's there in the form html. I figure if any piece of data comes through then they can all work.

Comment: @Dagon
I get the email with subject and the text/data description, but no actual data is passed.